# How to pass data from angular js controller to node.js server

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am passing some data from `angular.js` controller in following format:

```
data: { model: { title: 'hello'}, files: $scope.files}
```

I am able to get this in `node.js` by doing this:

`req.files`

Now I want to send one more data with existing data, so I tried doing this:

```
data: { model: { title: 'hello'}, files: $scope.files, id:newId}
```

but when I did `req.id`. I am getting `undefined`.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Files behaves differently since they are handled differently, if that makes sence :-) the rest of the data is in `req.body`

Comment: okay, so am  I passing `id:newId` data correctly?

Comment: I believe so. just try `console.log(req.body)` and you will see

Comment: Hmm, I just did that and got `{ model: { title: 'hello'} }`

Comment: Then the id needs to go into model `data: { model: { title: 'hello', id: newId },...`

Comment: Hmm, now I can see my data, but how can I store it's value to var? Like `req.body.id`?

Comment: Did you try it?? `console.log(req.body.id)`

Comment: yup, getting `undefined`

Comment: But you see the data right? `{ title: 'hello', id: newId }` if so then there's a chance it is string and not and object. If you use express.js then you need body parser https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

Comment: yup, im using bodyparse

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158792/discussion-between-molda-and-mayank-bisht).